# problems with passing html to the server with jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery

i have an ajax call

```
$.ajax({
                url: '<%=Url.Action("SaveDetails","Survey") %>',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                cache: false,
                data: { Id: selectedRow.Id, Value: surveyValue, FileName: filename, FileGuid: fileguid },
                success: function(data) {
                    ...
                }
            });
```

where the *surveyValue* is a html string. this call doesn't work. but is i change the surveyValue to an ordinary text i works fine.

how can i pass the html to the server?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you'll need to encode it:

```
data: { ... Value: encodeURIComponent(surveyValue), ... }
```

And on the server side:

```
string value = Server.UrlDecode(surveyValue);
```